# How to refer to a column created by .agg() function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have created code which uses `Groupby()` and `.agg()` to such that the new DataFrame has columns for `sum`, `mean`, and `count` of the values in `Total`.

```
test = df.groupby('Sector').agg({'Total': ['sum', 'mean', 'count']})
```

This code has worked and produced the results as necessary.
but when trying to use `sort_values()` to sort the `sum` column by descending. I encounter a problem.

```
test.sort_values('sum', axis="columns", ascending = False, inplace = True)
```

It will give me the output:
`KeyError: 'sum'`

I can't seem to find a way to refer to a column created by the `.agg()` function.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Total` column after `groupby` for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns and second proble need `sorting` by `index`, what is default value, so should be removed:

```
test = df.groupby('Sector')['Total'].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'count'])
```

```
#if use inplace=True cannot assign values
test.sort_values('sum', ascending = False, inplace = True)
print (test)
```

```
#if omitted, you need assign
test = test.sort_values('sum', ascending = False)
print (test)
```

Or if need custom columns names in [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
test = df.groupby('Sector').agg(sum1=('Total','sum'),
                                avg=('Total','mean'),
                                size=('Total','count'))
test.sort_values('sum1', ascending = False, inplace = True)
print (test)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment , it makes sense. but the output still remains `KeyError: 'sum'`.

Comment: @TKTK - I see it, second problem is `test.sort_values('sum', ascending = False, inplace = True)` - need `axis="index", what is default value,s o should be omitted.

Comment: How would i be able to make this as a dataframe? as it returns a `NoneType`

Comment: @TKTK - there is used `inplace=True`, so cannot assign, because output is `None` or remove it by `test = test.sort_values('sum1', ascending = False)`

Comment: @TKTK - Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `test.columns` to view columns names. Then use that column you need in the `sort_values`.

You have multindex columns that's your problems. Rename them.

```
test.columns = ["sum", "mean", "count"]
```

Or use the `multindex` column name in the sort_values

```
.sort_values(('Total', 'sum'), ascending = False, inplace = True) #without axis='columns'
```